# Detect round screen with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, screen, viewport, shapes, wearables

I am developing a framework to optimize websites for smartwatches. Currently I am using the Wear Internet Browser (WIB) on a LG Watch Urbane which you can get in the Android Play Store.

Well, most of the Android smartwatches have a round screen and it would be great if there is a way to detect those. With it I would be able to distinguish some important design principles.

Does anybody know a way to somehow detect those devices with round screens in jQuery?

Comment: Can you just test for the type of browser and have a set list of known round ones?

Comment: The user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; LG Watch Urbane Build/NXH19X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.77.34.5 Mobile Safari/537.36`. I'm not sure whether this string is different from other Chrome browsers. But it is at least a way to detect exactly this browser. Another possibility would be to check for the device name of those devices with round screens.

Comment: That would be difficult to maintain as new devices come out

Comment: if you did `alert(document.elementFromPoint(x,y))` where `x,y` would be off the screen, like the top right in between the edge of the screen and the corner, would it return an element or `null`?